# How to add a library to Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, shared-libraries

I want to add this [library](https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick) to my project but I am not sure how to. I have already searched for the answers online but most of them are for old versions and do not work. Can someone give me step by step instructions please?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a folder in your project calls libs (if there isnt one already). Place the library there. Then right click it and go to build->add to build path.

Comment: as in place the `.jar` files in the lib folder?

Comment: Yes. You need to paste your .jar file in libs folder.

Comment: After doing that what do I need to do.

Comment: @User1204501 After that you can freely use your library in your code and it should compile

Comment: I have got the .jars in the lib folder but then how do I use the library in my code?

Comment: After you added it to your build patch just make the calls to the library code. Just like you always do - import your.library.code; and then use whatever classes in that code you want.

Answer (score 1):

The most easy way to do this is :

add the souce file into your project,you also must add jars in lib dirctory into build  path,and files in res directory into your project.Another way to do this is :

1. download the source from github,import it into eclipse as a new projct "imagepick"
2. right click on the "imagepick" project ,choose export->java->JAR FiLE, export the project 
   as "imagepick.jar".And then put "imagepick.jar" into build path
3. put jars in lib directory into build path,put files in res directory into right place of your project